# Bluescreen of death during Java development on a Leopard - any ideas how to solve this?

Tags: java, macos, crash, intellij-idea, bsod

I develop using Java 5 and 6 on Intellij IDEA 7 and 9M1. From time to time (during run/compile) my Mac (10.5.7) will die with a Bluescreen of death.

Has anybody else had this issue and somehow managed to solve it? If so, how? Any suggestions other than running the IDE in a VM?

Comment: BSOD on a MAC??? BLASPHEMY! Mac's can do no wrong!! :P

Comment: Java development is the only application that managed to kill the machine so far.

Comment: I've the same configuration, but I avoid compiling from inside IDEA (also on Windows or Linux) and use my ant targets instead. With run or debug inside IDEA I never had any problems so far.

Comment: Kai: I could use ANT for running and compiling. I suspect that the culprit is in the AWT bindings from Apple so that might indeed solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be specific to your hardware and/or software environment. I'd suggest performing a hardware test (faulty memory is the most likely cause). Java is a stress to the system, I've seen such situations before (other applications work fine, but Java is causing system crashes, in most cases such problems were related to memory, replacing the modules fixed them). For testing the memory you can use the [Memtest OS X](http://www.memtestosx.org/joomla/index.php).

Another thing to try is Java for Mac OS X 10.5 Update 5 Developer Preview which is available via Apple Developer Connection.

Comment: Stupid I did not think of this, but it appears that indeed faulty memory seems to be the problem. I tested it using memtest (http://www.command-tab.com/2008/01/11/how-to-test-ram-under-mac-os-x/) and it reported errors during one test. I will exchange the memory but I am pretty sure that your suggestions was right on the mark.

Comment: Update: it was not (really) faulty memory but a combination of memory problems and heat! If I turn up the fan rotation using e.g. fan control.app the memory problems go away.

Comment: Yet another update: the problems are gone under Mac OS X 10.6 (Snow Leopard). Probably has something to do with the cold climate.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to file a bug against Apple's Java VM. This really should not happen.

Comment: It is probably also a bug in the Darwin OS.

Comment: I have submitted a dozen or so reports using the crash reporter that pops up after restart. Is there another way?

Comment: Allow Apple a year or two to fix the bug ;) Did you contact JetBrains, too? Their product is involved and they might be faster to react if you report a bug against 9M1.

Comment: I did not contact them because I suspected the Apple VM (or more specifically the AWT bridge) as the culprit. Now I've opened http://www.jetbrains.net/jira/browse/IDEA-24204 - maybe something will come out of it.

Answer (score 1):

I've heard people complaining about the latest MacOS Java updates in combination with IDEA. [Maybe check out this thread](http://www.jetbrains.net/devnet/thread/282406)

Answer (score 0):

Have you had a look at the system console (/Applications/Utilities/Console)? Java or the OS may have recorded some dying gasp there before the BSOD happened.

Comment: BSODs were also in Version 7. There were no log entries related to the crash except a few unrelated segfaults.